# HDMI and Bumblebee, Washed out Colors and Low Resolution

Tags: 12.04, hdmi, bumblebee

I’m on a Acer TimelineX 3830TG, Nvidia 540m, Ubuntu 12.04 using the bumblebee drivers.

I just connected my external monitor to my laptop using HDMI and there is output to it, however the contrast is all screwed up and the highest resolution I can set it too is 1680x1050, but on VGA I get 1920x1200.

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because your non-accelerated GPU is determining resolutions? Bumblebee forces the Optimus nvidia GPU to do the maths while the on board intel HD GPU does the drawing. Meaning while you get faster graphics, it's not being achieved solely by the nvidia GPU and is subject to the restrictions of the intel HD (or whatever you have).

Comment: Does it work when you don't use the bumblebee 'optirun'?

Comment: How do i run HDMI with optirun?I don't understand.

Comment: You can only run HDMI with Optirun if the Nvidia card is already enable before you connect the cable to your HDMI port. Reason is, the port is wired directly to the Nvidia card, so you have to edit Bumblebee's configuration files to do it. There is a guide on the Bumblebee project's git on how to do it. Currently, it is not working out of the box, I warn you.